# Disable battery critically low message Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, power-management

My battery is dead ad very hard to replace (ASUS ROG G751), so I am wondering how to turn off the "Laptop battery critically low" notification. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and Gnome 3. Thanks! [image]

Comment: If your battery is dead then I presume you always keep the AC adapter plugged in. Then how come it's showing the critical battery level alert?

Comment: @pomsky I added the picture. As I said I cannot take out the battery

Comment: @yuri What did you do? I am facing the same issue....

Comment: @Nikhil Not a great solution, but if you press and hold the power button for several seconds and then turn on the laptop again sometimes the problem goes away.

Comment: For me the following link worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143789/disable-message-laptop-battery-critically-low

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my ASUS ROG G751J and tried a number of solutions without success. It's almost impossible to get a replacement battery, so I ended up solving this by unplugging the battery. There is a number of videos on YouTube showing how to replace the battery, I followed along until the point where you lift up the keyboard, I could then get to the battery cable to unplug it without having to unplug any of the other ribbons (I did not remove the battery entirely as it's just too much hassle).